# C++ Memory leak while trying to delete first element of linkedlist of pointers

Tags: c++, list, memory-leaks

I'm quite new to C++ and I'm having a big problem for two days now.
I'm trying to do multithreaded rendering (raycasting, multisampling, ambientocclusion) with posix threads and everytime I run the program, it consumes about 5GB of RAM (after start of threads) until termination. So obviously I have a memory Leak. My working threads work like this:

```
struct Job
{
    AOSampler sampler;
    Ray ray;
    bool abool;
    int someint;
    .
    .
    //no pointers here
};
//global
//use of C++ STL list
list<Job*> * jobs;


//Part of thread posix function starts here
list<Job*> tjobs;
// Mark 1    

//Pushing and popping between "tjobs" the threadjobs just for this thread and the global jobpool "jobs". Of course threadsafe with mutex locking.
//The thread pops jobs from "jobs" and puts em into "tjobs"

while(!tjobs.empty())
{
    //many calculations but all vars are on stack, besides creating new jobs an pushing them to some other queue, which will be pushed into "jobs" later

    // !!!THE PROBLEM!!!
    delete (tjobs.front());
    tjobs.pop_front();
    // The memory in htop always rises but never decreases!
}
// jumps to Mark 1
// end of multithread while
```

The code is compiling and running and terminating on many cores but performance is bad(4 ok, 24 bad, its a 24 core machine). I think it might be because of the 5GB memory usage (quarter of all phys. ram), but well OS and cache might not be able to handle this well.

I'm desperate about finding a solution to my problem. My googling didn't help me at all. I hop you can do. any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you

(sorry for my english)

Edit1: forgot to mention, that it has no output yet -> I can't verify if it is valid

Edit2:
Some headers:

```
class AOSampler
{
public:
    AOSampler();
    /// constructor that initializes the sampler, just calls init
    AOSampler(vec3 const & normal, vec3 const & color);
    /// initializes the sampler
    void init(vec3 const & normal, vec3 const & color);
    /// returns an importance sampled random direction and the associated weight
    void sample(vec3 & sampledDirection, vec3 & sampleWeight) const;
private:
    /// orthonormal basis
    vec3 m_normal;
    vec3 m_tangent;
    vec3 m_bitangent;
    /// diffuse color
    vec3 m_color;
};

class Ray
{
public:
    Ray() : tMin(0.001f), tMax(FLT_MAX){}
    vec3 origin;
    vec3 direction;
    float tMin, tMax;
};

class vec3
{
public:
    float x,y,z;

    vec3();
    vec3(float a, float b, float c);

    /// assignment operator that assigns a single scalar value to all components
    void operator=(float v);

    /// unsafe element access 
    float operator[](unsigned int i) const
    {
        return (&x)[i];
    }

    /// length of the vector
    float length() const;

    ///Returns a normalized version of the vector
    vec3 normalize() const;

    /// componentwise summation
    vec3 add(const vec3& a) const;

    /// componentwise subtraction
    vec3 subtract(const vec3& a) const;

    ///compute the dot product which is cos(alpha) * this.Length * a.Length
    ///where alpha is the (smaller) angle between the vectors
    float dot(const vec3& a) const;

    float minComponent() const;
    float maxComponent() const;

    ///computes a vector which is orthogonal to both of the input vectors
    static vec3 cross(const vec3& a, const vec3& b);
    static vec3 min(const vec3& a, const vec3& b);
    static vec3 max(const vec3& a, const vec3& b);

    /// add a vector to this vector
    void operator+=( vec3 const & v );
    /// subtract a vector from this vector
    void operator-=( vec3 const & v );
};
```

Comment: It seems you have typos in your post. Instead, **copy & paste your debugging testcase** directly into Stack Overflow. Then we won't waste our time.

Comment: Are you accessing your tjobs list from multiple threads?  I don't see any sort of barriers in place for thread safe access of your jobs and list itself I'm pretty sure is not thread-safe.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I didn't manage to find out quickly how to paste in a code block here (4 whitespace s***, code has tab), sorry.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Yes I'm accessing them from numerous threads. Yes list is not threadsafe. Threadsafe access is needed because I do a lot of pushing and popping and getting the size on jobs. As neither of these operations is atomic, I have to do this.

Comment: @JoãoAugusto SomeObject is an selfwritten Class like "AOSampler"

Comment: @nullpoint.er: You can read the formatting FAQ. Click the orange question mark (`?`) alongside the posting box.

Comment: @nullpoint.er: He wants to know _precisely_ what it is. That means, we need its definition. As I said before, post a real testcase.

Comment: @nullpoint.er: So you're using threads on non-threadsafe code. Did we just solve this problem?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not allowed to post some parts ot the source to the internet. But I can give you the classes-headers (if neccessary the .cpp too), that are used in Job. Will edit now.

Comment: @nullpoint.er: No, I don't want your original source. I want a **testcase**. A made up, minimal, _complete_ example that compiles but demonstrates the problem, and contains nothing irrelevant to the problem. This is what you should be debugging with.

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop only loops while the list is empty, and you then try to delete the non-existent first element. Of course this is going to cause weird behavior. Or more likely, you've already put items into the queue and never pull them out which would cause it to grow forever.

So let's assume that you're not showing us your real code, but something you retyped and forgot a `!` character there and the while loop is correct.

In that case are you sure it's actually leaking? Your process may be using more memory but if it's freeing it (which it tentatively appears to be) the process will be able to reuse it even though the OS can't see the memory in htop. You can use valgrind to give you a much better picture of whether you're really leaking or not.

Comment: Yeah forgot the "!". No I'm not sure if it's leaking. Unfortunately I do not have the rights on the machine to install packages... I'll see fi I can manage to run it somewhere with valgrind.

Comment: @nullpoint.er valgrind is very easy to compile from sources, you don't need a package manager.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to detect memory leaks even if you have access to the source code. Try using a leak detection tool, such as Valgrind: http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/valgrind.html
It's good investment.